# Too many indices for array while using sklearn imputer class

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, imputation

I am practicing on datasets in machine learning and while getting of missing value, I used imputer class but it gave me a error of `too many indices for array`. For that error I just looked through all of the `numpy` module but I didn't get any idea to solve it.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as mlp
import pandas as pd

#import datasets
i_export = pd.read_csv("2018-2010_export.csv")
x=i_export.iloc[:, [0,1,3,4]].values
y=i_export.iloc[:,2].values

#splitting training test set
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.2,random_state=0)

#calculating missing data
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
impute=SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan,strategy='mean')
impute=SimpleImputer.fit(y_test[:,0])
y_test[:,0]=SimpleImputer.fit_transform(y_test[:,0])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that y_test is a one-dimensional array.  When you try to index `y_test[:,0]`, you're trying to index two dimensions.

You can make your `y_test` array into a two dimensional array with one column and "n" rows with this snippet `y_test = y_test.reshape(-1,1)`

Here's my change to your code.  I made some changes to the way you used the Simple Imputer.

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
imputer=SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan,strategy='mean')
y_test=imputer.fit_transform(y_test.reshape(-1, 1))
```

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

you can try method of DataFrame.fillna().Have fun in machine learning.